# Like condition for Boolean column in mysql

Tags: mysql

I have two use cases.

1. For all the columns in my table I am allowing user to search for contains. My query will be

`Select * from table where column like "%value%";`

When it comes to boolean columns and if they are searching for t/tr/tru/true I should be showing the results with

`Select * from table where column is true;`

Currently I am checking the entered string with a regular expression and hard coding the query. Is there a better way to achieve this ?

2. When the user query for equals to and the string contains special characters

   `Select * from table where column = "string with backslash escaped";`

This query does not work but if I use **like** instead of **=** it works.
But like doesn't work for boolean columns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use something like this to match against a boolean expression:

```
SELECT *
  FROM my_table
 WHERE IF(boolean_column, 'true', 'false') LIKE '%tr%';
```

Answer (score 0):

The `Like` clause can be used only on text type of data (i.e `VARCHAR`, `CHAR` etc). Your logic should be more of finding out column name being searched and based on that define which operators to use.

If you have option to use a view in place of this table, you can create a view on this table and convert `Boolean` column to text based column which would allow you to search that column like all others.